# Unable to insert opportunitylineItem in apex code?

Tags: apex, dml

```
public class NewMedicineBillVF1_Ctrl{
public Boolean displayPopup {get;set;}
public List<ProWrapper> pwrlist{get;set;}
private List<OpportunityLineItem> olilist;
public Product2 pro{get;set;}
public Opportunity opp{get;set;}


public List<PriceBookEntry> availableProducts {get;set;}
public List<ProWrapper> disWrpList {get;set;}

public NewMedicineBillVF1_Ctrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
displayPopup = false;
//String qString = 'select Id, Pricebook2Id, IsActive, Product2.Name, Product2.Family, Product2.IsActive,Product2.Description, UnitPrice from PricebookEntry where IsActive=true' ;
opp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
pwrlist= new List<ProWrapper>();

}


// Method to insert Medical Bill(Opportunity) 
    public void saveBill(){
        insert opp;
        system.debug('^^^^^^^^^^'+opp.id);
        }


       public void savemedicines(){
       system.debug('######## ' + disWrpList.size());
       for(ProWrapper pwr : disWrpList){
       if(oliList!= null){
       OpportunityLineItem oli1 = new OpportunityLineItem();
       system.debug('@@@@@@@' );
        oli1.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
         system.debug('@@@@@@@'+ oli1.OpportunityId ); 
        oli1.PricebookEntryId = '01uf4000000cuIHAAY';
         system.debug('!!!!!!!!!!!!' + oli1.PricebookEntryId );

        oli1.UnitPrice= pwr.pbe.UnitPrice;

        oli1.Quantity = pwr.oli.Quantity;
        oliList.add(oli1);
        }
      }

    insert oliList;
```

Comment: What problem/error do you have ?

Comment: Tried in different ways to insert but ended up getting these error : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION,
 field integrity exception: PricebookEntryId, unknown (versions 3.0 and higher must specify pricebook entry id, others must specify product id): [PricebookEntryId, unknown]

Comment: Attempt to dereference a null object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't looks to be doing good job in assigning the right reference fields.

I guess to create OLI you need to assign Opp Id, PriceBookEntryId, Quantity, UnitPrice.

Below is what I think this code should be doing, added some comments to so that its clear.

```
  public void saveBill() {
    insert opp;
    system.debug('^^^^^^^^^^' + opp.id);
    for(ProWrapper pwr : disWrpList){
        OpportunityLineItem oli1 = new OpportunityLineItem();
        oli1.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
        // oli.Pricebookentry.Product2.Name = pwr.p.id; // 1.you shouldn't have to enter this, you just populate the reference fiedls
        oli.PricebookEntryId = pwr.pbe.Id;
        // oli1.Product2id=pwr.p.id; // 2.like the errors said you dont have to enter productid as you are entering pricebookentry
        oli1.UnitPrice= pwr.pbe.UnitPrice;
        // oli1.Product2.Name= pwr.p.id; // same as 1.
        // oli1.Pricebookentry.Product2id= pwr.p.id; // same as 1
        // oli1.Product2.id = pwr.p.id; // same as 1
        oli1.Quantity = pwr.oli.Quantity;
        oliList.add(oli1);

    }
    insert oliList;


  }
```

Here is a sample test code to show how it works.

```
@isTest(seeAllData = true)
private class OppLineItemTest {
    static testMethod void testOliInsert(){
        List<PriceBookEntry> pbes = [SELECT Id, PriceBook2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE IsActive  = true AND PriceBook2.isStandard = true];
        if(!pbes.isEmpty()){
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                Name = 'Test Opp',
                StageName = 'Prospecting',
                CloseDate = System.today().addDays(1),
                PriceBook2Id = pbes[0].PriceBook2Id
            );
            insert opp;

            List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = new List<OpportunityLineItem >();
            for(PriceBookEntry pbe : pbes){
                olis.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
                    UnitPrice = pbe.UnitPrice,
                    Quantity = 1,
                    OpportunityId = opp.Id,
                    PriceBookEntryId = pbe.Id
                ));
            }

            insert olis;
            System.assertEquals([SELECT Count() FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId =:opp.Id],pbes.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried the above code but got the below mentioned error :

Comment: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: PricebookEntryId, unknown (versions 3.0 and higher must specify pricebook entry id, others must specify product id): [PricebookEntryId, unknown]
Error is in expression '{!saveBill}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page newmedicinebillvf1: Class.NewMedicineBillVF1_Ctrl.saveBill: line 39, column 1

Class.NewMedicineBillVF1_Ctrl.saveBill: line 39, column 1

Comment: If you look at the above error you posted, it still looks like you are assigning ProductId

Comment: @B1sfdc also added a unit test class to show how records should be inserted

Comment: @ Avidev9 : FYI  in the above code productId is commented and tested, but still getting the field integrity error...the issue is with Pricebookentry Id's, which pricebookentryid has to be assigned to oli.pricebookentry. I have tried inserting with particular pricebookentry id (hardcoded), it got inserted. Now the issue is how to get the id from wrapper class. Could you suggest the way